# Setting nth bit of unsigned int

Tags: bitwise-operators

Given a unsigned int x, I want to set the nth bit to y, and y can be either 0 or 1. Is it possible to create an expression using bitwise operators to do this while avoiding the use of any conditional statements? Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x = (x & (~(1 << n))) | (y << n)
```

Quite simple. (First, clear the `n`th bit, and set `n`th bit to `1` if `y` is `1`.)

Comment: Still this has a condition, even if it is in one line.

Comment: Thank you! I never considered doing it this way.

Comment: @Eun By condition I meant without having to check the value of y using an if-else statement or something similar.

Comment: ...or, more cleaner: `x = (x | (1 << n)) & (y << n)` - this version sets `n`th bit to 1 in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
x ^= (-y ^ x) & (1 << n);
```

Comment: This is not unconditional. OP wants this without any condition

Comment: I am aware of this, but I am wondering if it is possible to incorporate y into the expression so that both cases (with y being 0 or 1) can be handled with one statement.

Comment: @Eun Sorry you're right, I missed that. Fixed my answer.